# Trying to populate a combobox in winrt xaml from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to populate a drop down with data from an xml file I'm sure I'm close because intellisense shows data out of the XML file but when I try to bind it to the combobox I get each entry that has the type of data but not the data.

```
public void PopPrograms()
{
    //string picprgrmsXMLPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Assets/PicPrograms.xml");
    string picprgrmsXMLPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.Path, "PicPrograms.xml");
    //string picprgrmsXMLPath = @"C:\temp\PicPrograms.xml";
    XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(picprgrmsXMLPath);

    var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("Node")
    select new PicPrograms
    {
        //ProgramID = (string)query.Element("pID"),
        ProgramName = (string)query.Element("pName"),
    };
    cbProgram.ItemsSource = data;
```

and now here is my xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbProgram" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="55,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" Height="32" 
          SelectionChanged="cbProgram_SelectionChanged" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something here but just don't know what it is.

Here is a snippet of the xml doc:

```
<Programs>
  <Node>
    <pID>9930FA1A-A59E-4F78-8AFF-2E07AD4C1CD8</pID>
    <pName>Black and Gold</pName>
  </Node>
  <Node>
    <pID>23B4263C-4BF2-4EC3-AD99-17BCD6301189</pID>
    <pName>Darren Hawkins Pic Review</pName>
  </Node>
```

The resulting combobox shows the same thing for each element:

```
CameraCapture.CapturePhoto+PicProgram
```

Comment: please post your `ToString` method of `PicProgram` and your `ItemTemplate`

Comment: sorry don't know what you are talking about

Comment: do you have a `override string ToString()` in `PicProgram`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to tell the `ComboBox` control what to display, you need to set either its `DisplayMemberPath` or `ItemTemplate`.  (It calls `ToString()` on the object otherwise, which by default returns the type name, as you noticed.)

Eg:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbProgram" DisplayMemberPath="ProgramName" ...
```

Or:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbProgram" ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProgramName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```